# suggestion to read JSON inside a CSV file without parsing in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file that also has JSON inside it. I am trying to get Company, Type, Driver into a dataframe 
I don't want to parse it as the below CSV is just a sample, I have a lot more columns with various json key/values (some are absent, not in a specific order, and lots and lots of them).

my sub-short_csvjson.csv CSV file sample:

```
Married,Transportation,Color
YES,"{""Company"":""GTS"",""Type"":""Limo""}",White
,"{""Driver"":""John""}",Green
NO,"{""Type"":""Van"",""Driver"":""John""}",
```

What can I do (outside of parsing) to have a dataframe with

```
my_data$Married
my_data$Transportation.Company
my_data$Transportation.Type
my_data$Transportation.Driver
my_data$Color
```

Thanks

Comment: why are you so against parsing?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I just don't think parsing is an efficient way of doing it. I probably have 30 different JSON objects where their key/values are in different order, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution I can think of that gets you what you need using `jsonlite` package and row-by-row processing:

ASSUME `df` looks like this using `read.csv` and `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`:

```
df
  Married                  Transportation Color
1     YES {"Company":"GTS","Type":"Limo"} White
2                       {"Driver":"John"} Green
3      NO  {"Type":"Van","Driver":"John"}
```

You can do this:

```
library(jsonlite)

l <- lapply(df$Transportation, fromJSON)
n <- unique(unlist(sapply(l, names)))
df[, n] <- lapply(n, function(x) sapply(l, function(y) y[[x]]))
```

To get this:

```
df
  Married                  Transportation Color Company Type Driver
1     YES {"Company":"GTS","Type":"Limo"} White     GTS Limo   NULL
2                       {"Driver":"John"} Green    NULL NULL   John
3      NO  {"Type":"Van","Driver":"John"}          NULL  Van   John
```

Not sure if there is a more efficient way.

**EDIT BASED ON ADDED INFORMATION ABOUT MALFORMED JSON IN REAL DATA**

In case there is malformed JSON in the original within the `Transportation` column, here is one way to solve it:

Original data frame as follows:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Married,Transportation,Color
YES,"{""Company"":""GTS"",""Type"":""Limo""}",White
,"{""Driver"":""John""}",Green
NO,"{""Type"":""Van"",""Driver"":""John""}",',
header = TRUE, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Row bind and extra row with malformed JSON with an extra '"' character:

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(Married = 'NO',
                           Transportation = '{"Company": ""GTLS"}',
                           Color = 'Red'))
```

New df looks like this (See malformed JSON in row 4):

```
  Married                  Transportation Color
1     YES {"Company":"GTS","Type":"Limo"} White
2                       {"Driver":"John"} Green
3      NO  {"Type":"Van","Driver":"John"}      
4      NO            {"Company": ""GTLS"}   Red
```

Now, use this to get all the nested JSON into separate columns:

```
l <- lapply(df$Transportation, function(x) tryCatch({fromJSON(x)}, error = function(e) NA))
n <- unique(unlist(sapply(l, names)))
df[, n] <- lapply(n, function(x)
                    sapply(l, function(y)
                             if (!is.null(names(y))) y[[x]]))
```

Output is as follows:

```
  Married                  Transportation Color Company Type Driver
1     YES {"Company":"GTS","Type":"Limo"} White     GTS Limo   NULL
2                       {"Driver":"John"} Green    NULL NULL   John
3      NO  {"Type":"Van","Driver":"John"}          NULL  Van   John
4      NO            {"Company": ""GTLS"}   Red    NULL NULL   NULL
```

Comment: Hi @Gopala, I am getting EOF error after running 


l <- lapply(df$Transportation, fromJSON)


Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Can you see what `str(df$Transportation)` is? Also, it is possible that you don't have properly constructed JSON in the original data. You can modify the function to 'catch' this error and return NA for those values doing something like this `lapply(df$Transportation, function(x) tryCatch({fromJSON(x)}, error = function(e) NA))`.

Comment: when I run str, I get a character, ex

`chr [1:48] "{\"Company\":\"GTS\",\"Type\":\"Limo\",\"Driver\":\"John\"}"...`


I also modified the function but then when I got to 

`df[, n] <- lapply(n, function(x) sapply(l, function(y) y[[x]]))`

I get:  `Error in y[[x]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I corrected x to df in `l <- lapply(x,` but this still didn't produce extra columns. I also get this when I run against my file (50 warnings of the below:

`1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , n, value = list(structure(list( ... :
  replacement element 1 has 12847 rows to replace 48 rows`

Comment: Sorry - the error in computing `l` which should have been `df$Transportation`. I edited. Beyond that, I have no idea what is going on in your data. I ran it on a totally different machine with a clean R console and works fine.